# Keras model is interpreting my input data as one image in 4D not lots of separate images

Tags: python, keras

I have the network model_classifier, which is the RCNN/classifier component of Faster-RCNN in the middle of a training loop.

```
loss_class = model_classifier.train_on_batch([X_batch_for_classifier, X2_batch], [Y1_batch, Y2_batch])
```

Producing the error message:

> InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 1605632 values, but the requested shape has 100352 [Op:Reshape]

The input tensor shape for model_classifier is (None, 300, 300, 3).

The shapes for the two sets of inputs and two sets of labels are as follows:

```
X2_for_classifier:  (16, 300, 300, 3)

X2_batch:           (16, 4, 4)

Y1_batch:           (16, 4, 4)

Y2_batch:           (16, 4, 24)
```

I am putting in 16 training examples in in the hope that it will treat all 16 as separate, but it is instead treating all as one training example as a 4D image. I get the same problem regardless of whether I input them as tensors or np.arrays.

I have also tried converting the inputs and targets into a tf.data.Dataset format but that just gives the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have fixed it now, the problem was with my network not my data entry.

Where you define the ROIPoolingConv class you have to swap this:

```
final_output = K.reshape(final_output, (1, self.num_rois, self.pool_size, self.pool_size, self.nb_channels))
```

for this:

```
final_output = K.reshape(final_output, (-1, self.num_rois, self.pool_size, self.pool_size, self.nb_channels))
```

Where the -1 creates a "None" dim to the output tensor to allow for a variable batch size.